# Shiny - elements are not being rendered once function is complete

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am dynamically creating the elements to be inserted into a `fluidRow`, the problem that I am facing is that all elements are being rendered at once. So, instead of rendering each element when its `renderUI` function ends, they all keep waiting until the last `renderUI` finishes. Thus, having lots of elements in `my_dataset` makes the rendering really slow.

I expected that once the `print(str_glue('End: {i}'))` was shown, the element would be rendered. However, this was not the case, it kept waiting for all elements (including ones that were not visible on screen).

I tried using the `outputOptions(..., suspendWhenHidden = TRUE)` but it made no difference (as it was expected since this is the default).

**MWE**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(shinycssloaders)

qtd <- 500

my_dataset <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  Name = rep('Sample', qtd),
  Value = runif(qtd)
)

ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, textInput(inputId = 'my_text_input', label = NULL, placeholder = 'Search', width = '100%')),
      uiOutput('custom_ui')
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[['custom_ui']] <- renderUI({
    filtered_dataset <- my_dataset %>%
      filter(grepl(input[['my_text_input']], Name, ignore.case = T)) %>%
      arrange(Name)
    
    map(1:nrow(filtered_dataset), function(i) {
      item <- filtered_dataset[i,]
      custom_id <- str_glue('custom_id_{i}')
      output[[custom_id]] <- renderUI({
        print(str_glue('Start: {i}'))
        print(item)
        result <- box(
          width = 3,
          title = item$Name,
          item$Value
        )
        print(str_glue('End: {i}'))
        result
      })
      
      column(width = 3, uiOutput(custom_id, style = 'height: 350px;') %>% withSpinner(type = 6))
    })
  })
}


runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = T)
```

Comment: You've not given us a MWE, so it's difficult to be sure, but... `renderUI` is a function.  It will only return once all the code it contains has executed.  Hence you don't see anything until you see everything.  Options to improve the speed: (1) move the construction of the dataset outside the renderUI.  (That's good practioce, and I suspect you'll have to do it anyway.)  2  Since you're effectively duplicating the same interface (with different data) define a module to represent the interface and the create multiple instances of the module to display the different data cuts.

Comment: @Limey I added a MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the expected behaviour. The server will not return anything to the UI before all calculations are finished.

I see you are relying a lot on `renderUI`. This tends to make the Shiny app slow. When the app starts, it must load, realize that it lacks a portion of the UI, ask the server to create the UI - then the server will create the HTML for all of your boxes and send them to the UI before anything is shown. You should try to keep as much as possible of the UI static.

Dependent on what you want to achieve there are probably a lot of different ways of doing it without `renderUI`.

Under is an example where the HTML for the boxes are created outside of `renderUI`. This will work, as long as you don't need input controls or outputs in the boxes - because then they need their own ID.

---

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

qtd <- 500

my_dataset <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Name = rep('Sample', qtd),
  Value = runif(qtd)
) %>%
  mutate(
    x = map2(
      Name,
      Value,
      ~column(
        width = 3,
        box(
          width = 3,
          title = .x,
          .y
        )
      )
    )
  )


ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        12,
        textInput(
          inputId = 'my_text_input',
          label = NULL,
          placeholder = 'Search',
          width = '100%'
        )
      ),
      uiOutput('custom_ui')
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Only the filtering of the data is done inside `renderUI`
  output[['custom_ui']] <- renderUI({

    filtered_dataset <-
      my_dataset %>%
      filter(grepl(input[['my_text_input']], Name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
      arrange(Name) %>%
      pull(x)

  })

}


runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

---

> Last I just want to recommend [this book](https://mastering-shiny.org/) by Hadley Wickham. I think reading this (or parts of this) book before working with Shiny will make everything easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference book, I'll take a look into it! Your solution indeed works like a charm for de MWE that I put up, but for my real problem unfortunatily it doens't =/. Just like you commented, I do have some outputs that I need to set there dynamically, but do not worry! I already found a work around for my problem that worked for me =) . Once again, thanks for your time!